# .css() for 'animation-delay' attribute cannot be set with variable

Tags: jquery, css, animation, delay

I cannot use a variable to change the 'animation-delay' css property.

Note: This will work for something like background color or other animation attributes. The animation-delay will also work with a string '10s' but not a variable--even when the variable is explicitly set to a string.

```
var animationDelayTime = '10s'  
$('.my-animation-class').css({  
  'animation-delay' : animationDelayTime  
})
```

The this other method also does not work:

```
$('.my-animation-class').css(  
  'animation-delay', animationDelayTime  
)
```

This currently works:

```
$('.my-animation-class').css({  
  'animation-delay' : '10s'  
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wt0wzgg2/)

Comment: Can you create demo on jsfiddle.net with your complete code

Comment: Seems easier to just use `$(selector).delay().queue()`

Comment: Uncommenting what you wrote in your fiddle works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/wt0wzgg2/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created jsfiddle - this is working for me. Maybe you have an issue elsewhere?

```
<div class="my-animation-class"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var animationDelayTime = '10s'  
    $('.my-animation-class').css({  
      'animation-delay' : animationDelayTime  
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.my-animation-class{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#ff0000;
     -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; 
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    position:relative;
}


@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 200px;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 200px;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sthAngels/3bc30t9k/

Comment: @user3390658 I created it before you posted yours, but here is your example: http://jsfiddle.net/sthAngels/33c4hzjm/3/, for me is working fine on Chrome and FF

Comment: Yep, have mine wrapped in a function and I defined the variable I was using outside the function. Once I moved them into the same function as the css part it worked. Thanks so much

Comment: @user3390658 great that you problem is solved now, and thanks for accepting the answer